# Не(двуличен) своим поведением

Tags: прилагательные, отрицание

Задумалась мне задумка одна - как ведёт себя краткое прилагательное с частицей **"не"**, слитно или раздельно, когда есть подозреваемый на "зависимое слово".

*Не убивший выстрелом снайпер сам был убит*

Здесь "выстрелом" - зависимое слово в творительном падеже, значит, **не убивший"** пишется раздельно. А что делать с прилагательными?

*Не двуличен своим поведением тот, кто не умеет обманывать*

С одной стороны можно, наверное, заменить как бы на **"Простоватый"**:

*Простоват своим поведением тот, кто не умеет обманывать*

По такой логике частица **"не"** должна писаться слитно.

Вопрос таков: нужно ли писать отрицательную частицу "не" раздельно от краткого прилагательного, если есть зависимое слово, как это происходит при разделении "не" от причастий с зависимым словом, или можно написать слитно?

Comment: Привет! Сформулируйте, пожалуйста, яснее, в чём именно ваш вопрос и почему информация, уже доступная вам, кажется недостаточной для того, чтобы на этот вопрос ответить.

Comment: Всё, отредактировано

Answer (score 1):

Наличие зависимых слов практически не влияет на написание частицы "не" с кратким прилагательным. Есть только один случай: если в зависимом слове есть приставка, либо частица "ни", то "не" с кратким прилагательным пишется отдельно.

Они ни в чём не похожи друг на друга; Эта река никогда не спокойна.

Там существует ряд других факторов, как наличие противопоставления:

Книга не интересна, а скучна.

А также вкладываемый автором смысл.

По Розенталю.

«В зависимости от смысла частица не с краткими формами прилагательных может писаться то слитно, то раздельно; ср.: наша семья небогата (‘бедна’) — наша семья не богата (‘среднего достатка’); эта девушка некрасива (утверждается отрицательный признак) — эта девушка не красива (отрицается положительный признак); адрес неизвестен (отрицается «известность»); Невелика беда — дождь. — Не велика, казалось бы, эта дистанция для стайеров»

Подробнее http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77

Логическое ударение тоже играет роль.

Таким образом, в вашем случае, возможны оба варианта.

Comment: Благодарствую, мудрый человек!